# Google Slides: Create a multiline paragraph from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm trying to insert multiple lines into a paragraph using the [setText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#setText(String)) method, but all newline characters `\n` are converted to new paragraphs (as when you press Enter in the editor) instead of new lines in a single paragraph (as when you press Shift+Enter in the editor). I tried also `\r` char, but it does nothing.

```
SlidesApp
 .getActivePresentation()
 .presentation.getSelection()
 .getCurrentPage( 
 .asSlide()
 .getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.BODY)
 .asShape()
 .getText()
 .setText('First line\nsecond line');
```

[image]

Is it somehow possible to insert multiline text to the shape without creating multiple paragraphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Shift+Enter in the editor inserts a vertical tab(soft enter/return) instead of a hard return. You can use

```
\v
```

instead of `\n`